# Indexing rows in Autoloader when loading from parquet files

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-live-tables, databricks-autoloader

Simply saying I have an autoloader doing ingestion of parquet files which contains CDC events. Sometimes commit time for two events is the same and I want to take order of row inside parquet file to be second criteria for ordering events. Basically I need row number but can't use `row_number()` and `monotonically_increasing_id()`. Additionally as this is inside DLT I can't rely on `foreachBatch()`.

I know that there is something like `METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER` in Snowflake, so I'm searching for something similar in Databricks.